# Cannot navigate to dynamically added page in jquerymobile / phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I just cant figure out where I am going wrong. I want to create a page dynamically in jquerymobile. Then append it to body and navigate to it when clicking on a link. Here is what I try:

In my html I've got a second page, which is sort of a basic structure for the dynamically generated one. So I clone it and append it to body. The action is triggered on "pagecreate" of the active page (but triggering it on pagebeforeshow or pageshow doesnot change anything).

```
$('#basic-page').clone().attr({'id':'uniqueid'}).appendTo($.mobile.pagecontainer);
```

Then I make it live like a page...

```
$('#uniqueid').page();
```

And finally I add a link to the active page.

```
$('#activepage .content').append('<a href="#uniqueid">Test</a>');
```

But when I click this link, nothing happens. What is wrong? Im Running jquerymobile 1.3.2 on phonegap 2.9.0

Comment: I also tried to append it to `$('body')` - didnot change anything!

Comment: instead of cloning append a new page `$('<div/>, { 'data-role': 'page', id: 'foo', 'data-theme': 'e' }).appendTo('body'); $.mobile.changePage('#foo');`. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/d7YWy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of cloning a page, create a new page and modify it the way you want.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/d7YWy/)**

```
$('<div/>', {
    'data-role': 'page',
    id: 'foo',
    'data-theme': 'e'
}).appendTo('body');

$.mobile.changePage('#foo');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try having something like.

```
$("#uniquieid").on("vclick", function (e) {
  // Do your stuff here
  // or navigate to the desired section of the page.
  $.mobile.changePage("#uniqueid");
  e.preventDefault();
});
```